# Issue with executeQuery after upgrading to 2.2.4

Tags: grails, grails-orm

We upgrarded our application from 2.0.3 recently and facing issue with execute query sometimes. We need to fetch list of records to display in UI and the total counts of the list to display pagination. In both the places we are using executeQuery method to fetch the data. While fetching the data we are not having any issue but while fetching the total count of the eligible records the JVM is crashing and the application is hanged. We cannot proceed further without restarting the Server and the services running on the machine.

Here is the query which we are using to fetch the count :

```
select count(camp) from Campaign as camp   
where (  camp.domainId=-1 AND  (camp.status not in ('X')) )  
AND  camp.campaignType IN ('B','I') order by camp.startDate desc
```

We were using the same queries in 2.0.3 and never faced any issue. After upgrading to 2.2.4 we are facing the issue and this issue is not consistent. This is the log after crashing:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
Internal Error (javaCalls.cpp:59), pid=6236, tid=5144
guarantee(thread->is_Java_thread()) failed: crucial check - the VM thread cannot and must not escape to Java code
JRE version: 7.0-b147
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+3
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
cmlui.CMLCampaignService.getCampaignCount(Ljava/lang/Object;ZLcmlui/GUIUser;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+570
cmlui.CMLCampaignService.getCampaignCount(Ljava/lang/Object;ZLcmlui/GUIUser;)Ljava/lang/Object;+121
cmlui.CMLCampaignService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f623839b.invoke(ILjava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+2937
net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+19
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint()Ljava/lang/Object;+24
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()Ljava/lang/Object;+19
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(Lorg/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInvocation;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()Ljava/lang/Object;+101

org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lnet/sf/cglib/proxy/MethodProxy;)Ljava/lang/Object;+112
cmlui.CMLCampaignService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$69c262f0.getCampaignCount(Ljava/lang/Object;ZLcmlui/GUIUser;)Ljava/lang/Object;+349
cmlui.CMLCampaignService$getCampaignCount.call(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+122
```

Comment: How many records are we counting (approx)? Why do you need `order by` while counting rows?

Comment: We are counting max of 500 records.  The where clause building is same for both retrieving all the records and getting the count.

Comment: The problem was with exeingcuteQuery method. After changing it to session.createSQLQuery it worked.